# x and y must have same first dimension

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy, fft

I am getting value error: "x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (662534,) and (331267, 2)"
my code

```
from scipy import signal
import scipy as sy
import scipy.fftpack as syfp
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
array = np.loadtxt("file1.csv", dtype = np.float, usecols = (0,1), delimiter = ',')
lenght =len(array)
x = sy.linspace(0.00001, lenght*0.00001, num=lenght)
FFT = syfp.fft(array)
freqs = syfp.fftfreq(array.size, d=(x[1]-x[0]))
plt.subplot(211)
plt.plot(x, array)
plt.subplot(212)
plt.plot(freqs, sy.log10(FFT), 'x')
plt.show()
```

Comment: It'd be easier with the complete traceback. Still, considering that `331,267 * 2 == 662,534`, it could be that two sequences are chained whilst they shouldn't, or vice-versa...

Comment: The error is pretty self-explanatory...

Comment: The "answers" you put below are no answers. Please [edit] your question if you want to provide more details. Note that StackOverflow is not a discussion forum; it consists of questions and answers. Please take the [tour]. Also, don't forget to [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) the answer that solves your issue.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please read the tour as @ImportanceOfBeingErnest mentioned, it will guide you how to ask question properly, so that you could get the right answer :)

Comment: Sorry Guys, new to the place, I will read the tour and do the correction.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is `FFT` and `freqs` has different dimension, you could use [flatten](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flatten.html) to format FFT to be one demension:

```
from scipy import signal
import scipy as sy
import scipy.fftpack as syfp
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
array = np.loadtxt("file1.csv", dtype = np.float, usecols = (0,1), delimiter = ',')
lenght =len(array)
x = sy.linspace(0.00001, lenght*0.00001, num=lenght)

FFT = syfp.fft(array)

FFT =  FFT.flatten()
print FFT.shape
freqs = syfp.fftfreq(array.size, d=(x[1]-x[0]))
print freqs.shape
plt.subplot(211)
plt.plot(x, array)
plt.subplot(212)
plt.plot(freqs, sy.log10(FFT), 'x')
plt.show()
```